# doxyqml not documenting qml files properly

Tags: c++, qt, qml, documentation, doxygen

I'm documenting my qml files using doxygen, for supporting .qml files, i installed doxyqml but this is also not documenting all the functions inside the file. For example,

```
Item {
    id: mainV
    property real ct: 0.5
    signal sectionHdrUnselect()
    function onOkClicked()
    {
            msgDlgId.close()
    }
    ListView {
        id: view
        property var collapsed: ({})
        function hideSection( section ) {
        }

}
```

In this sample .qml file, here only onOkClicked() function, property real ct, signal sectionHdrUnselect, ListView view are getting documented whereas the function, properties inside ListView is not getting documented.

Why is it not getting documented in doxygen?
Is there any way I can document all the properties, signals, functions in .qml file?

These are the changes in configuration file which are different from default configuration settings(generated using cmd: doxygen -x doxyfile).

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = docs
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = qml=C++
TIMESTAMP              = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
SHOW_HEADERFILE        = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = NO
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.h \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.qml
RECURSIVE              = YES
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.qml=doxyqml
GENERATE_QHP           = YES
QCH_FILE               = MyApp.qch
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.myapp
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
GENERATE_XML           = YES
PREDEFINED             = WIN32 \
                         Q_OS_IOS \
                         Q_OS_ANDROID \
                         Q_OS_WINDOWS
DOT_COMMON_ATTR        = "fontname=FreeSans,fontsize=10"
DOT_EDGE_ATTR          = "labelfontname=FreeSans,labelfontsize=10"
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which settings (different from the default settings, i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) are you using? Doxygen doesn't know about qml files, so you probably used doxyqml as input filter? What is the output of `doxyqml` (i.e. the result of `doxygen -d filteroutput`) ?

Comment: @albert im using doxygen version ***1.10.0***, im using doxyqml 0.5.3,

Comment: @albert i executed `doxygen -d filteroutput`, output i got is this

`class Nesting : public QtQuick.Item {
public:

Q_PROPERTY(real ct READ dummyGetter_ct_ignore)

Q_SIGNALS: void sectionHdrUnselect(); public:

void onOkClicked();
private:
ListView view;
};`

Comment: Please add the extra information into the original question (especially due to the limited edit possibilities in comments). What are the settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`) you use? The `ListView` looks like a sub structure, but it looks like it isn't  properly translated by `doxyqml` (as the property `` and the signal `hideSection` don't appear in the result from `doxyqml`. Also `ListView` is marked private and private elements are omitted by default unless `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` is set to `YES` (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_private).